# Is it possible to query blockchain using wallet extra-infos?

Tags: query

I read [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15154/methods-of-attaching-data-to-an-ethereum-address) how to add extra fields to a wallet address, is it possible to query the ethereum blockchain and find all wallets with the same extra-filed? For example: all wallets with the same user name?